# Serial Monitor Not Displaying Code From Setup or Main - Baud 9600

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

In setup() the I have Serial.begin(9600), but there is no text being displayed whenever I have the Serial Monitor print anything. I have tried moving the location of the print() functions (including directly under Serial.begin()), but nothing has worked.

```
#include <Stepper.h>
#include "CommandTest.h"
#include "BlueSide.h"
#include "RedSide.h"
#include "GreenSide.h"
#include "YellowSide.h"
#include "OrangeSide.h"
#include "WhiteSide.h"

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1);
  Serial.print("test"); //not displaying even this
  char temp[] = "wwwwwwwww";
  WhiteSide::setValue(temp);
  strcpy(temp, "rrrrrrrrr");
  RedSide::setValue(temp);
  strcpy(temp, "bbbbbbbbb");
  BlueSide::setValue(temp);
  strcpy(temp, "ooooooooo");
  OrangeSide::setValue(temp);
  strcpy(temp, "ggggggggg");
  GreenSide::setValue(temp);
  strcpy(temp, "yyyyyyyyy");
  YellowSide::setValue(temp);
  delay(1000);
}

void printCube(){
  Serial.println(WhiteSide::getArray());
  Serial.println(RedSide::getArray());
  Serial.println(BlueSide::getArray());
  Serial.println(OrangeSide::getArray());
  Serial.println(GreenSide::getArray());
  Serial.println(YellowSide::getArray());
}

int main(){
  CommandTest command;
  Serial.print("start");//not displaying this
  command.f();
  printCube();//and it's not printing these arrays
  delay(1000);
  command.fp();
  printCube();
  delay(1000);
  command.r();
  printCube();
  delay(1000);
  command.rp();
  printCube();
  delay(1000);
  command.l();
  printCube();
  delay(1000);
  command.lp();
  printCube();
  delay(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Arduino sketch you do not need to write a `main` function. The only required functions are `setup` and `loop`.

Your locally declared `main` is being used instead of the one supplied by the Arduino core (this is allowed because the arduino `main` comes from a library, so your `main` supercedes it). Therefore `setup` is never called.

Rename your `int main()` to `void loop()` and remove the `return 0;` from the end.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious, but did you consider adding the setup() function to main?  Without actually enabling the serial module you're not likely to see anything.  It has been a while since I've used an Arduino, but from what I recall, setting up the serial output was fairly simple.

You may also want to check that your wiring is correct.  An oscilloscope will work quite well in this case, however a simple review may also suffice.